# Openshot crashes on startup

Tags: linux, debian, crash

Using Debian testing

When I try to start Openshot it crashes. I have tried three ways to install it: Regular packages, Flatpak and AppImage, but I get the same result from all of them.

Error message:

```
 main_window:ERROR Unhandled crash detected... will attempt to recover backup project: /home/me/.openshot_qt/backup
     ui_util:WARNING Icon theme media-playback-start not found. Will use backup icon.
 main_window:INFO updateStatusChanged
         app:INFO Process command-line arguments: ['/tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/launch']
 main_window:INFO recover_backup
 main_window:INFO Recovering backup file: /home/me/.openshot_qt/backup/backup.osp
project_data:INFO Setting default profile to HD 720p 30 fps
project_data:INFO 2.1.0
project_data:INFO 0.1.1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openshot::InvalidFile'
  what():  File could not be opened.
Caught signal 6 (SIGABRT)
---- Unhandled Exception: Stack Trace ----
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ( abort                                     + 0x121 )  [0x7f063e71d535]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (                                           + 0x8c943)  [0x7f063d0a5943]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (                                           + 0x92896)  [0x7f063d0ab896]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (                                           + 0x91989)  [0x7f063d0aa989]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ( __gxx_personality_v0                      + 0x2c5 )  [0x7f063d0ab2d5]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (                                           + 0x10d73)  [0x7f063e8f2d73]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 ( _Unwind_Resume                            + 0x125 )  [0x7f063e8f35f5]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libopenshot.so.16 ( openshot::QtImageReader::QtImageReader(std::string)  + 0x8b  )  [0x7f062d96456b]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libopenshot.so.16 ( openshot::Mask::SetJsonValue(Json::Value)  + 0x37b )  [0x7f062d91b97b]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libopenshot.so.16 ( openshot::Timeline::SetJsonValue(Json::Value)  + 0x269 )  [0x7f062d973819]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libopenshot.so.16 ( openshot::Timeline::SetJson(std::string)  + 0x99  )  [0x7f062d965949]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/_openshot.so (                                           + 0x8aa29)  [0x7f062dc3fa29]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x654b)  [0x7f063eb08fbb]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6742)  [0x7f063eb091b2]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6c5c)  [0x7f063eb096cc]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6c5c)  [0x7f063eb096cc]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6c5c)  [0x7f063eb096cc]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6c5c)  [0x7f063eb096cc]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6742)  [0x7f063eb091b2]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x209fa6)  [0x7f063eb0cfa6]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyObject_Call                             + 0x68  )  [0x7f063ea6e758]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x15159d)  [0x7f063ea5459d]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyObject_Call                             + 0x68  )  [0x7f063ea6e758]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords             + 0x47  )  [0x7f063eae49b7]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/PyQt5.QtCore.so ( PyQtSlot::invoke(_object*, _object*) const  + 0x50  )  [0x7f063da48840]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/PyQt5.QtCore.so ( PyQtSlot::invoke(void**, _object*, void*) const  + 0xcf  )  [0x7f063da48caf]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/PyQt5.QtCore.so ( PyQtSlotProxy::unislot(void**)            + 0x62  )  [0x7f063da53762]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/PyQt5.QtCore.so ( PyQtSlotProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)  + 0x57  )  [0x7f063da540d7]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libQt5Core.so.5 ( QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**)  + 0x8ad )  [0x7f063d45136d]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/PyQt5.QtCore.so (                                           + 0x1ed9c9)  [0x7f063da559c9]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6d79)  [0x7f063eb097e9]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x209fa6)  [0x7f063eb0cfa6]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyObject_Call                             + 0x68  )  [0x7f063ea6e758]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x15159d)  [0x7f063ea5459d]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyObject_Call                             + 0x68  )  [0x7f063ea6e758]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0xcabf9)  [0x7f063e9cdbf9]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x174636)  [0x7f063ea77636]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyObject_Call                             + 0x68  )  [0x7f063ea6e758]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x44cd)  [0x7f063eb06f3d]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6c5c)  [0x7f063eb096cc]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCode                           + 0x3b  )  [0x7f063eb0d10b]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (                                           + 0x24d6ed)  [0x7f063eb506ed]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalFrameEx                        + 0x6d79)  [0x7f063eb097e9]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCodeEx                         + 0x886 )  [0x7f063eb0c976]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 ( PyEval_EvalCode                           + 0x3b  )  [0x7f063eb0d10b]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/launch ( main                                      + 0x777 )  [0x404117]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ( __libc_start_main                         + 0xeb  )  [0x7f063e71f09b]
  /tmp/.mount_0ATLjX/usr/bin/launch (                                                   )  [0x404425]
---- End of Stack Trace ----
```

What should I do to make it work? Or should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error message is "'openshot::InvalidFile' what():  File could not be opened", you might check if a file you had been editing was moved, removed or damaged. Clear the MRU list.

*Specifically:* @Broman has found: "I removed ~/.openshot_qt/backup/backup.osp and it worked.

Another possibility is that the package was improperly installed and that an essential file is missing.

Comment: I removed `~/.openshot_qt/backup/backup.osp` and it worked. You can edit your answer to target this specific file.